"TypeError: 'ChatCompletion' object is not subscriptable" error
Running next code and got an error. Help me please to fix! Thanks in advance
Here is my code:
def get_completion_and_token_count(messages, 
                                   model="gpt-3.5-turbo", 
                                   temperature=0, 
                                   max_tokens=500):
    
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model=model,
        messages=messages,
        temperature=temperature, 
        max_tokens=max_tokens,
    )
    
    content = response.choices[0].message.content
    
    token_dict = {
'prompt_tokens':response['usage']['prompt_tokens'],
'completion_tokens':response['usage']['completion_tokens'],
'total_tokens':response['usage']['total_tokens'],
    }

    return content, token_dict
 
messages = [
{'role':'system', 
 'content':"""You are an assistant who responds\
 in the style of Dr Seuss."""},    
{'role':'user',
 'content':"""write me a very short poem \ 
 about a happy carrot"""},  
] 
response, token_dict = get_completion_and_token_count(messages)

And this is the result I got after running the code above.
TypeError: 'ChatCompletion' object is not subscriptable

error
I am expecting the issue is fixed. I tried to uninstall/install openai, changed model to 4, but it did not work unfortunately

The properties of the chat completion object (docs) should be referenced as properties, not using dict syntax. Replace
token_dict = {
  'prompt_tokens':response['usage']['prompt_tokens'],
  'completion_tokens':response['usage']['completion_tokens'],
  'total_tokens':response['usage']['total_tokens'],
}

with
token_dict = {
  'prompt_tokens': response.usage.prompt_tokens,
  'completion_tokens': response.usage.completion_tokens,
  'total_tokens': response.usage.total_tokens,
}

